# Check if THIS clicked TD's value matches the value of an array

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a battleship game, everything works except for this one thing. And I can't seem to figure out the correct way you would do this. I want to check if the clicked TD's value matches a value in an array, if it does change the innerHTML to hit(which is an X). (this) represents the clicked TD. Can you use indexOf in this scenario?

```
    function play() {
           if ((this).value == shipLocations.indexOf((this).value)) {
                (this).innerHTML = hit;
           }
       else {
          (this).innerHTML = miss;    
        }
   }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. It jumps into the else statement on every possible clickable td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script>
    var shipLocations = ["5"];
    function play(button) {
        if (-1 != shipLocations.indexOf((button).value)) {
            (button).innerHTML = "hit";
        }

        else {
            (button).innerHTML = "miss";
        }

    }
</script>
<button value="5" onclick="play(this)">meh</button>
```

assumes ship locations are stored and not ship objects

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how would I re-write my condition according to your solution? It feels like your IF should return "miss" and not "hit"?

Comment: -1 means it wasn't found. So basically `if ('value' is not "not found")... `

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you're comparing apples and oranges. `indexOf` returns the index of the value you're looking for in your `shipLocations` array and not the actual location of a ship stored in the array.

**Update**

The fiddle shows, that you're also accessing the *value* attribute in the wrong way.
The following is the correct way:

```
if (parseInt((this).getAttribute("value")) == shipLocations[shipLocations.indexOf(parseInt(this.getAttribute("value")))]) {
        (this).innerHTML = hit;
}
```

`this` refers to the html element and not a javascript object, where you could use a `.` to access attributes. Using `getAttribute("value")` works.

*Sidenote:
The ships are sometimes positioned so that they "touch". I thought that was illegal ;-)*

Comment: Ye I kinda got that feeling as well but I don't know how to change it so that I compare the value of a td that is also an item in the array?

Comment: Well, you need to use the index you're getting and retrieve the actual location: `shipLocations[shipLocations.indexOf(this.value)]`

Comment: That makes every click result with a hit instead of vice versa. I'll give you a fiddle of the whole thing hang on.

Comment: Ok now it works, thank you. One thing though which I found odd, if if's a match, it displays the "miss" and not "hit".. When I changed it to != instead of == it showed the correct symbol, why is this?

Comment: And about the touching, I haven't gotten that far yet :P

Comment: `getAttribute` returns a string. So, you need to use `parseInt()` in order to convert it to a number. Unfortunately, without parsing the logic of the if-else is reversed because you only have the *value* attribute on the "hit" cells and then the first expression evaluates `false` because you have `value == undefined` whereas a "miss" cell leads to `undefined == undefined` which is true.

Comment: You're definitely better of by just checking if the cell is in the `shipLocations` array as @raw did.